# How to use the CALL and SMS permission like truecaller does

Tags: android

How to allow the permission of CALL and SMS like truecaller allows the user when Google play strictly restricted it instead. My application is based on the CALL and SMS interface, I dont know how to use these permissions when it is been restricted. Can anyone please suggest it!

Answer (score 1):

These permissions are not totally restricted to use. There are certain permitted uses and exceptions for these permissions.

The permitted cases include if your app is intended for Default SMS handling.
If you think your app falls under the permitted uses, you will have to fill this google [form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfCnRaa4b1VuHhE4gVekWJc_V0Zt4XiTlsKsTipTlPg5ECA7Q/viewform) (form link is also available on the support page below) and let them know about this.

More Info: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303

Do read it.

Comment: But the form submission will be just extended to march 9 2019, after that google play will restrict it permanently...

Comment: You will have to submit the form on or before 9th Jan. If Google decides that your app does not meet the permitted uses, then you will have an extended date til 9th March.

But if it does meet the permitted case, you will be allowed to keep the permissions.